# document.referrer get blank

Tags: javascript, html, iis, redirect

I have set up error pages in IIS as an httpRedirect.htm, trying to convert any http request to https, when error 403.4 is caught.

So if a user types a http url to the browser, it triggers httpRedirect.htm page and will get this url, replace http to https and then redirect to this new url. I want this happen in javascript.

However, when I use document.referrer in httpRedirect.htm, I found it always returns blank.

Is there any special consideration for this situation? Can the browser using this error page carry the information from the previous request?

Comment: You can never rely on document.referrer. And deocument.referrer is ALWAYS blank when coming from a bookmark or typed in address. Use information in the URL

Answer (score 0):

You will have to look at the location object. The redirect is on the server-side.

Scenarios:

1. You go directly to http://example.com/index.html, and
   httpRedirect.htm is rendered. Since that´s the first page you are
   visiting, the referrer is empty.
2. You are at http://test.com/index.html and clicks on a link to
   http://example.com/index.html. You are now seeing httpRedirect.html,
   but the referrer is the page before, which is
   http://test.com/index.html.

Since the referrer depends on your browser, you can´t be sure to have anything in the referrer object at all, even if it "should" be something there. Some firewalls and anti-virus applications might disguise is at well.

If you are at http://example.com/index.html and is seeing httpRedirect.htm, the location.href is still http://example.com/index.html though.

You can see some example code using location here:
http://kloudgate.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/how-to-redirect-http-to-https-using-iis7-0/